How to make the cloth rope simulation attached at both points?
I'm creating a trebuchet simulation. All of the actual mechanics are handled by rigid bodies and rigid body constraints, but I wanted to add a rope between the "holder" and the arm. I followed this tutorial, where you basically create a plane, create hooks at both ends and parent those hooks to the rigid bodies. However when I tried doing so, the rope stayed connected to the arm side but didn't stay connected to the holder side, resulting in weird behavior which you can see in this gif:

I attempted to fix this a couple times before (with the same rigid body bake) and the first result was slightly different, but the rope still was connected to the arm but not to the holder. If anyone knows how to fix this, I'd be really grateful.
Here's the .blend file:


There were a couple mistakes that caused this:

I forgot to parent the holder side to the holder
I parented both ends to the arm end by mistake and
I forgot to move the arm end controller to the arm from the middle.


That is what my usual comment is on things not working like in a tutorial: check if you followed it closely and did everything like they did, maybe redo it completely (since a tutorial should teach you something) and make sure that the Blender version in the tutorial and yours are matching - not always necessary, but sometimes things can be very different between versions. Perhaps you want to try a more recent tutorial on a trebuchet, try this one by Blender Made Easy: Build a Working Trebuchet in Blender: Rigid Bodies Tutorial
